# Appointing a number to a variable

Tags: c

is there a possibility that a variable which is not appointed a number be appointed negative number by compiler?

I use Dev C++ and it prints "0", but what about other compilers?

Example:

```
int x;
printf("%d", x);
```

Dev C++ output: 0

Comment: You're invoking undefined behaviour by accessing an uninitialized variable, anything can happen; so yes, it is a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Not initializing your variable is undefined behavior under any compiler.

So yes, you could have positive, negative number, or zero.

Comment: "Undefined behaviour under any compiler"? It's undefined behaviour under the standard, and any normal compiler implicitly defines the behaviour (as whatever that compiler makes the program do).